# Is toString() called when a reference of String class is printed in JAVA?

Tags: java, string, reference

When printing a reference of any other type than a String, the output is the name of the class along with the HashCode / the string returned by its toString() method. But when a reference of a String is printed, the actual "string values" is shown, is toString() called in this case ?
[image]

Comment: Yes and if your class only has one String field it will be handled as a String.

Comment: bcoz `String` overrides `toString()`

Comment: can you show code or examples of the output please?

Comment: Check the `toString()` method on the Object class, which has a different implementation of the `toString()` method on the String class.

Comment: System is a class, with a static field out, of type PrintStream. So you're calling the println(Object) method of a PrintStream.

Comment: @pshemo wrong duplicate, IMO. The person is not asking why they get the `class@hash` format, but whether `println` calls the `toString` method.

Comment: `out` in `System` class holds `PrintStream` and that class has `println(String x)` to print strings without need to `toString` call. But `PrintStream` also has `println(Object o)` method to handle printing objects from other classes (with help of `String.valueOf` which internally is using `toString`).

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes I know. I was meant to add this as *additional* duplicate but apparently original duplicate target was from flag, not close-vote so it disappeared. I am looking for better duplicate now.

Comment: Related: [toString() method within System.out.println() a double call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570937/tostring-method-within-system-out-println-a-double-call)

Answer (score 2):

No. If you look at [the source code for `println(String)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28java.lang.String%29), you'll see:

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

The only difference between this and the generic `Object`-signature version is that `String.valueOf` is not called:

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

and `String.valueOf` is the method which contains the call to `toString`:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

---

You should get used to browsing the source files of the JDK if you're curious about details such as this.

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051481/how-an-object-will-call-tostring-method-implicitly

Comment: @sForSujit Isn't it subtly different? That question is "how is `toString` called for `Object`s?" and this question is "*is* `toString` called for `String`s?"

Comment: I am confused. If toString() is not called, then how is the string value getting displayed ?

Comment: @shOm A string is a sequence of characters. That's the *only* thing you *can* print. When you try to print an object, it implicitly converts that object to a sequence of characters so it can print it. When that object is already a sequence of characters, it doesn't need to do anything.

Comment: @Michael, I followed what you said, but, we do not pass the actual objects of Strings to the println() but their references are passed, isn't it ?

Comment: At some levels deeper, the getChars method of String gets called to get the actual string data.

Comment: @ShOm "but, we do not pass the actual objects of Strings to the println() but their references are passed, isn't it" yes, but what exactly is confusing you here? JVM via that reference is able to access object it represents so if we have `String s = "foo";` then `s` holds reference to `"foo"` object. But we can write `s.charAt(0)` and JVM will understand that we want to get character at index `0` from object which `s` holds reference to.